# gnome.Shell.desktop: ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc handshake failed

Tags: 18.04, gnome, xrdp

I am using Xrdp to remote control my Ubuntu-18.04 desktop, but often disconnected because of reasons I can't understand. At first I thought the machine is dead, but when I went to check out Ubuntu-18.04, it seemed not, its power was still on but I just couldn't use the desktop, the screen was black and couldn't be woke up. So I shut down the machine and checked the syslog. It seemed that GNOME Shell failed to establish an SSL connection? I'm not quite sure.
Here is the syslog of the error info:

```
May 23 17:37:22 wpc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[28929]: [29684:29689:0523/173722.627148:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(941)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
May 23 17:42:31 wpc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[28929]: [29645:29665:0523/174231.692311:ERROR:checkin_request.cc(223)] Failed to get checkin response. Fetcher failed. Retrying.
May 23 17:44:01 wpc CRON[17974]: (root) CMD (   test -x /etc/cron.daily/popularity-contest && /etc/cron.daily/popularity-contest --crond)
May 23 17:45:01 wpc CRON[17981]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
.........
May 23 18:45:01 wpc CRON[18601]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
May 23 18:45:31 wpc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[28929]: [29645:29665:0523/184531.733290:ERROR:checkin_request.cc(223)] Failed to get checkin response. Fetcher failed. Retrying.
```

System info:

- Ubuntu-18.04
- Xrdp: 0.9.5
- Gnome: 3.38.2

Comment: It looks like something wrong with your crontab? I am having this SOCKET HANDSHAKE errors, but I think mine may be related to VPN.